# How can i send canvas dataurl to input file type parameter? rails, html

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas

This is my goal,

```
user uploads a file and crop the img size what we wants.

cw1canv2 is the canvas element that have been cropped.
```

I got the canvas's data-url like this,

var imgData = document.getElementById('cw1canv2').toDataURL("image/png");

in imgData, it shows like this.

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAG0AAABtCAYAAACr+O9WAAAgAElEQVR4Xu1VERYLONGVERYLONG...
```

ok so now i have to send this to the server with request param.

this is my front code,

```
<%=f.hidden_field(:photo)%>
```

and inserted the dataurl like this

```
$("#photo").val(imgData);
```

finally, the request param in like this,

```
"photo"=>"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAG0AAABtCAYAAACr+O9WAAAgAElEQVR4Xu1debBlR13+9d3fvJk3W2ayTJKZyTpZSYCQhEUkEAQKKIhKlE3FAFqgIiVUUa5VVGEVf1CgYCGKUFCUFBbFIiIGUYIiIBAlSoJZZjKTWTLrm/fevPW+e4/f9+vuc/r0PXd7GWYe4Z6annPfWbv76++39XLM8g93JmbrMTHjsyLldmJE8K94S0S6nm/P4OSkJIJHy
```

but the problem is, the server-side developer wants to send the data like this,

```
"photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000005481368 

@original_filename="logo.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition:

 form-data; name=\"om_user[photo]\"; filename=\"logo.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",

 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20140306-2624-nntf44>>
```

This is the normal file upload case with input file type.

```
<%=f.file_field(:photo)%>
```

How convert dataurl to like this kind of format?